# Getter vs Computed property. What would warrant using one of these approaches over the other?

Tags: ios, swift

Take a look at this variable

```
var username: String {
    get {
        return self.twitterAccount.valueForKey("username") as! String
    }
}
```

The compiler doesn't complain when I remove the get, presumably because it is simply treated as a computed property.

```
var username: String {
    return self.twitterAccount.valueForKey("username") as! String
}
```

What would warrant using one of these approaches over the other ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both forms are exactly the same thing, a read-only computed property.

From the documentation:

> You can simplify the declaration of a read-only computed property by
>   removing the get keyword and its braces.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have a getter you can do this simplification. But if you also have a setter you have to use the former version in order to separate both.